# Vertical table alignment figures and equation

Tags: tables, graphics, equations, vertical-alignment

I need a table where each row has two images and an equation (matrix), however the vertical alignment is going crazy.

How do I specify that both figures and the equation are vertically aligned?

Image and code is below.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Point Cloud     & Convergence & Fabric Tensor \\
    \hline
    \includegraphics[width= 4.5cm]{figures/MILDataAll/2.png} &
    \includegraphics[width= 4.5cm]{figures/MILDataAll/ani1.png} &
    \(\begin{bmatrix}0.026&-0.912&-0.41\\-0.996&-0.056&0.063\\-0.081&0.407&-0.91\end{bmatrix}\) \\          
    \hline

\end{tabular}
```

\end{table}

Comment: welcome to tex.se! more simple is answer your question if you will extend code snippet to complete small document. for example one of possible solution is `\includegraphics[width= 4.5cm, valign=m]{figures/MILDataAll/2.png} ` ... however this is without knowing document preamble  not very useful to you ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: Boxes (everything in LaTeX is a box) are aligned by their baselines.  Images have their baseline at the bottom.  Equations have their baseline in the center.  One can use \raisebox to adjust the baseline.  For example, \raisebox{-0.5\height}{...} will center an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

extract from my testbed containing code of your table is:

```
    \begin{table}%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|>{$}c<{$}|}
\hline
Point Cloud &   Convergence &   Fabric Tensor   \\
\hline
\inserigraphics{figures/MILDataAll/2.png}       
    &
\inserigraphics{figures/MILDataAll/ani1.png} 
    &
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.026   &   -0.912  &   -0.41\\
    -0.996  &   -0.056  &   0.063\\
    -0.081  &   0.407   &   -0.91
    \end{bmatrix}   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

and extract of relevant part of preamble is:

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcommand\inserigraphics[1]{% shortnes for case that all images has the same width
    \includegraphics[width= 4.5cm,valign=m, margin=0pt 3pt 0pt 3pt]{#1}%
                            }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
```

beside this are other possible solutions (see [John Kormylo's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/34505/john-kormylo)  comment above. however all move images' and equation's baseline so, that they become vertical aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Use `adjustbox` and the `valign=c` key:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx, adjustbox}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200E}{}%{Left-to-Right!!!}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Point Cloud & Convergence & Fabric Tensor \\
    \hline
    \adjincludegraphics[width= 4.3cm, valign = c]{AliceSteadman} &
    \adjincludegraphics[width= 4.3cm, valign = c]{Charles-Dodgson} &
    \(\begin{bmatrix}0.026&-0.912&-0.41\\-0.996&-0.056&0.063\\-0.081&0.407&-0.91\end{bmatrix}\) \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]